# Is libstdc++ support for std::unordered_map incomplete?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, allocator, libstdc++

Related to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/31528/23476) on CodeReview, I tried to use `std::unordered_map` with a custom allocator but apparently this does not work with gcc/clang and libstdc++. The error can be generated from initializing an empty hash map with a `std::allocator`

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    typedef std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int>> A;
    typedef std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, A> H;    

    auto h = H{A()}; // ERROR, cannot find constructor H::H(const A&)
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6f500ce8a9b749c).

**Question**: is libstdc++ support for constructing `std::unordered_map` with a single allocator as argument incomplete?

**UPDATE**: further inspection shows that, for almost all containers other than `std::vector`, uses of allocators in libstdc++ access typedefs and member functions of allocators directly, rather than through `std::allocator_traits`. This works for `std::allocator` but fails for all custom allocators, unless they verbosely add those members and typedefs directly.

Comment: I think this is c++0x issue, since there are many online docs not providing the specific constructor. You need a language lawyer for the specifics, though. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fstandlib%2Fref%2Fheader_unordered_map.htm

Comment: On the GCC trunk unordered containers support C++11 allocators. I hope to finish converting the remaining containers to use `allocator_traits` in time for GCC 4.9

Comment: @JonathanWakely Those updates would be greatly appreciated! Are there any subtleties for that? Replacing occurances like `__Tp_allocator::bla` with `std::allocator_traits<__Tp_allocator>::bla` seems straightforward, but maybe I'm underestimating things?

Comment: Hahaha! if only ;-) just indirecting through `allocator_traits` is easy, but supporting allocator propagation and adding all the additional constructors takes more work, not to mention validating that stateful allocators, scoped allocators, and custom pointer types work, and getting the exception specifications right, and of course writing tests. See slide 26 onwards in http://accu.org/content/conf2012/JonathanWakely-CXX11_allocators.pdf

Comment: @JonathanWakely damn, I should have known being a STL maintainer required something more than mastering s//g ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In latest [doxygen docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01579_source.html#l00112) generated on 2013-08-01, it's there on line 178:

```
explicit
unordered_map(const allocator_type& __a)
: _M_h(__a)
{ }
```

However, in the docs for [4.8.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/libstdc++/api/a01624_source.html) it's not there, which is the same as my local one. As as far as g++4.8 is concerned its not implemented.

[Found the link to the patch](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/commit/60eba405d23ddeb2d0a289d2b79bebdd89b7c01b#diff-8c50ced5fa68eb0104ac755c2b227f7b). It was dated 2013-04-22, which was a little after the release of 4.8.

Comment: @TemplateRex: np, too bad their library is not as up-to-date as their compiler.