# Does boost::unordered_set<> work with the boost::container::scoped_allocator<> in 1.54 / C++03?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, unordered-map, allocator

I'm using Boost 1.54 with GCC 4.4.7 on CentOS 6, compiling for C++03 and am interested in using the Boost container library to add support for passing an allocator with state down through a hierarchy of nested containers:

This seems to work fine for the containers that come with the boost container library, but not for the hashing boost::unordered_(multi)set/map<>? Are the boost unordered containers part of a different library? Do they not yet support the new allocator model of C++11?

If not, can they be made to? 
Has anyone done this?
Is a patch available, perhaps?
If not, what's involved in adding this support myself?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18913388/819272

Comment: @x13n : errors? well, firstly, if I instantiate, say, 'boost::unordered_map<int,X> m(alloc)' where X is a class that does not support default construction (because, for example, it requires a mandatory allocator argument at construction) then just any about any subsequent use of 'm' fails to compile .e.g. m[3] ; // fails to find X:X()

Comment: @TemplateRex : related? thanks, yes, sort of, though i am specifically asking about the **boost** implementation of the hash containers.